# How to space text in a button

Tags: html, css

Have a task where I have some information in a button that needs to all be aligned to the same sides.

Its a digitized phone menu so the info on the left size is the line name and the information on the right is the lines extension. I want to align all of the extensions right.

I used buttons that activate Modals with more information. The buttons are required for the form of modal I am using. (Or at least that is what I found in research.) 
Tried paragraph tricks but they broke the buttons function.

```
<button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".HPENET_MODAL">2 - HPE Networking ................................................... XXXXX</button>
```

Comment: How is your button defined? a <div> with float:right might work if it's an <a> tag with css to make it look like a button.  I don't think this works for an <input type=button"> tag though

Comment: I added a code example of my button

Comment: Note that a `button` element can include HTML. So figure out how to do it outside of a button, then put it in the button.

Comment: I tried and thought it broke but will try again. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried wrapping it in a label, styling, that and applying `display:none` to the `button` element?

Comment: It worked simply using float and paragraph tags

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
<button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".HPENET_MODAL" style="width:500px;text-align:left">2 - HPE Networking <div style="float:right">XXXX</div></button>
```